# How to disable the 'Authentification required popup' in Spring server configuration?

Tags: spring, browser, spring-security, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

The route `/gateways` needs authentication.
When `/gateways` is accessed in the browser I am redirected to `/login` and the following form appears:

[image]

If `/gateways` is accessed from an angular2 app the following popup appears:

[image]

My spring security configuration is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static String REALM="Authentication";

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("cris").password("123").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("felix").password("felix123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http

                .httpBasic()

                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

                .and()
                .formLogin()

                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user", "/vehicles", "/signin", "/isautheticated").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

 // Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be present
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }

    /* To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }
```

So how can the popup be disabled?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify `formLogin()` instead of `httpBasic()` in your configuration. your configure method should look like this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http

            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login");

            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

            .and()
            .formLogin()

            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user", "/vehicles", "/signin", "/isautheticated").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
```

Comment: If I don't put the `HttpBasic` the login is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think your request from angular2 is taking an invalid `Authorization` Basic header, it was handled by `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, and it threw a `AuthenticationException`, and start to entry point.
You can implement your own entry point that implements `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, and then inject to `BasicFilter`, the default entry point is `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`. As you can see, it will return a `WWW-Authenticate` response header.

```
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + realmName + "\"");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                authException.getMessage());
    }
```